# How to use a custom windows docker container on gitlab-ci shared runner

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab-ci

i have a repository which consists of following two files, which builds an windows docker container with visual studio buildtools installed and pushes it to the registry provided by gitlab for my repository

`./Dockerfile`

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809-amd64

RUN powershell mkdir .\TEMP\;`
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe -OutFile .\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe; `
    .\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362


ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

`./.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
docker-build:  # Official docker image.
  tags: 
    - windows
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" .
    - docker push "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
```

so far this works perfectly

now in another repository i want to use this image to build my application on

`./.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
build-app:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/valerij/windows-builder:master
  tags: 
    - windows
  stage: build
  script:
    - "docker images"
    - "dir C:\\BuildTools" 
    - "cl --version"
```

which fails with

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.4.1 (e95f89a0)
  on windows-shared-runners-manager Hs8mheX5
Preparing the "custom" executor
Using Custom executor with driver autoscaler dev (6184f4a)...
Creating virtual machine for the job...
Virtual machine created!
Preparing environment
00:11
Running on PACKER-5F1153D4 via 
runner-hs8mhex5-wsrm-4464870f601125122949...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/valerij/ci-test/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out f7535d50 as master...
git-lfs/2.8.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.2; git 30af66bb)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
WARNING: Starting with version 14.0 the 'build_script' stage will be replaced with 'step_script': https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26426
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore   ltsc2019            561b89eac394        7 months ago        3.7GB
$ dir C:\BuildTools
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\BuildTools' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir C:\BuildTools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\BuildTools:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Now I notice that the log is missing anything along the lines familiar from another project

```
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:2d840844f8e7594a542b30eaed0a3451f5d84b9f85d091d09abc8e0ae75c48e4 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:60a3bda0eb90be8fa78830f284671d4c231e91878bbe5bd1c953aedda141014a ...
```

It seems to me that the windows runner ignores the `image` keyword.

How do I force the windows runner to use my custom docker image to perform the CI in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, but you might be able to work around it

Shared windows runners [do not process `image` or `services`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/build_cloud/windows_build_cloud.html#limitations-and-known-issues), so you can't set it that way. You should still be able to pull the other image and then execute commands / scripts inside it normally though.

e.g.,

```yaml
build-app:
  tags: 
    - windows
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - "docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - "docker images"
    - "docker run -v %cd%:%cd% -w %cd% $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE cl --version"
```

You may need to adjust the mounts, path, etc. to your use case